# Tracking file load progress in Python

Tags: python, file, load, progress

A lot of modules I use import entire files into memory or trickle a file's contents in while they process it.  I'm wondering if there's any way to track this sort of loading progress?  Possibly a wrapper class that takes a callback?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do by this by determining the size of the file, and then simply dividing the total by the number of bytes read. Like this:

```
import os

def show_progress(file_name, chunk_size=1024):
    fh = open(file_name, "r")
    total_size = os.path.getsize(file_name)
    total_read = 0
    while True:
        chunk = fh.read(chunk_size)
        if not chunk: 
            fh.close()
            break
        total_read += len(chunk)
        print "Progress: %s percent" % (total_read/total_size)
        yield chunk

for chunk in show_progress("my_file.txt"):
    # Process the chunk
    pass
```

**Edit:** I know it isn't the best code, but I just wanted to show the concept.

Answer (score 3):

If you actually mean "import" (not "read") then you can override the import module definitions.  You can add timing capabilities.

See the [imp](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-imp.html) module.

If you mean "read", then you can trivially wrap Python files with your own file-like wrapper.  Files don't expose too many methods.  You can override the interesting ones to get timing data.

```
>>> class MyFile(file):
...     def read(self,*args,**kw):
...         # start timing
...         result= super(MyFile,self).read(*args,**kw)
...         # finish timing
...         return result
```