# Tracking csv load in python

Tags: python, file

I would like to show the progress of processing a csv file.
I've searched and found this:
[Tracking file load progress in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468238/tracking-file-load-progress-in-python)
But this it will make my life a bit harder, because I'll need to process the bytes read.
Another approach is to count the lines but I wouldn't like to read the number of lines before start to process.

My idea is to get the file size(OS), and as I'm processing the file I get the bytes processed (should be the fastest approach).

Any other solution to show the progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [file.tell()](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=ftell#file.tell) but I haven't used it. It should give the position in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could ball-park it, right? The csv is just a text file, and you can grab the file size from the `os` module. Then, from the first line you read in, you can calculate the size of each line, and estimate the total lines in the file.

---

Clicking through your link, though, it appears that this is exactly the same suggestion :)

Comment: Ok, that is my idea. But how do I get the number of bytes read each iteration? FileObjects don't have a attribute like 'bytesRead'. And I want to iterate  over the lines, not read in bytes chunks.

Comment: you use the **len** operator on the data your getting.

Comment: Ahh ok, I see. Then I'd count the number of characters in one line, which gives you the number of bytes. This gives you an idea of bytes per line, total size of the file in bytes divided by this number gives the total number of lines in the file. You can also keep a moving average (i.e., update the bytes/line calculation each time you read a line) so that your estimate gets more accurate as you read more data.

Comment: Hm, I got your idea now. Bad that the comments don't have a way to mark as usefull :(

Comment: No worries---should've been more clear about my idea in the post. PS: Upvote the answer that you selected :)

Comment: @DanimarRibeiro Actually the comments do have a way to mark useful, hover over them and notice the up arrow.